# Can you retry on AssertionError with RetryTemplate?

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to modify my retry template to retry when an `AssertionError` is thrown?  If so, how?

Here's my `RetryTemplate` bean, with which `AssertionErrors` are not caught:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRetry
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();

        FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        fixedBackOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(1000l);
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);

        SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(5);
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);

        return retryTemplate;
    }
}
```

Other exceptions result in correct retry so it must be the throwable type.

Comment: You can try to catch `AssertionErrors` and wrap them rethrow by wrapping with an exception. Guess retry template triggered by catching exceptions but not errors.

Comment: I considered that but at that point it's dirty enough that I'd rather write my own retry code

Answer (score 0):

By default `SimpleRetryPolicy` reties only for Exception and its subclasses. You can specify the exception like this:

```
 @Bean
    public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();

        FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        fixedBackOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(1000l);
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);

        SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(5, Collections.singletonMap(AssertionError.class, true));
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);

        return retryTemplate;
    }
```